# Metafor: How to get confidence interval for I^2 in fixed-effect meta-analysis

Tags: r, metafor

I'm trying to get a confidence interval for the I^2 heterogeneity statistic from a fixed-effect meta-analysis I've run using the R package metafor.

It seems like the confint() function doesn't work for fixed effect meta-analyses?

Appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Hi You'll need to show us some code/ short data summary - then if it's a code problem maybe we can help, if it's a stats problem we can pass it on to stats stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption of fixed effects meta-analysis is that there is no heterogeneity in the effect. All differences in the observed effects are assumed to be due to sampling variance. As I^2 is the proportion of observed variance attributable to heterogeneity rather than sampling variance, metafor does not estimate an I^2 value when you use a fixed effect model (see below for sample output using fixed and random effects). This is why you cannot obtain the confidence interval around the I^2 value.

```r
library(metafor)
#> Warning: package 'metafor' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading 'metafor' package (version 2.0-0). For an overview 
#> and introduction to the package please type: help(metafor).

rma(yi = yi, vi = vi, data = dat.bangertdrowns2004, method = "FE")
#> 
#> Fixed-Effects Model (k = 48)
#> 
#> Test for Heterogeneity: 
#> Q(df = 47) = 107.1061, p-val < .0001
#> 
#> Model Results:
#> 
#> estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub     
#>   0.1656  0.0269  6.1499  <.0001  0.1128  0.2184  ***
#> 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

rma(yi = yi, vi = vi, data = dat.bangertdrowns2004)
#> 
#> Random-Effects Model (k = 48; tau^2 estimator: REML)
#> 
#> tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0499 (SE = 0.0197)
#> tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.2235
#> I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   58.37%
#> H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  2.40
#> 
#> Test for Heterogeneity: 
#> Q(df = 47) = 107.1061, p-val < .0001
#> 
#> Model Results:
#> 
#> estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub     
#>   0.2219  0.0460  4.8209  <.0001  0.1317  0.3122  ***
#> 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Created on 2019-02-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).